# PhpStorm to implement interface methods in a file template

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a file template

```
<?php
namespace $Namespace;

class ${NAME} extends \Zend\Db\AbstractTable implements
    $Implements
{
    const TABLE = '$Table';
}
```

Where the creator is asked to enter an interface that the class they're creating implements, this interface will contain a number of methods that the class should implement.

Does anybody know if there's a way to have a template implement the interfaces of a method that the user is defining upon creation?

Comment: Nope -- it can only do what Velocity engine allows (+ built-in variables). You would need to do this via plugin path if you want to have it done all in one go -- perhaps custom dialog for your File Template (e.g. similar to how built-in "New | PHP Class" works) and then process the generated file afterwards invoking needed IDE functionality (generate missing interface methods is just few clicks -- `Code | Generate | Implement methods...`. For missing abstract/interface methods they even have dedicated inspection/intention(quick fix)).